# IntelliJ header template for xml files

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-14

I wanted to create a template for my xml files and include it.

Here a part of my template:

```
<!-- Created by ${USER} on ${DATE} at ${TIME} -->
```

The variables USER, DATE and TIME are not set when it is to create a xml via the Android `New Layout Resource File` template generator.

Comment: Works fine for me.  What was the file extension that you placed in the config?

Comment: None it's into a include that I call e.g. in the Android templates with this #parse("File Header.xml") my template is read but the variable are not set up.

I've tried in a created template, it's working but not into the JAVA EE templates supplied in the IDE

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by "included".  Could you provide us with more information?

Comment: Here : http://imgur.com/IICn19y
this is where my template doesn't work, in the `Templates` tab I've created a template to test if my include is working and it does! But it doesn't for the `layoutResourceFile.xml`

Comment: same issue for me - predefined variables like ${DAY} ${MONTH_NAME_FULL} ${YEAR} does not injects inside android layout resource files.. ((